# Scope of 4th argument for pthread_create function in C threading

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Let us create a global variable to change it in threads
int g = 0;

// The function to be executed by all threads
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
  // Store the value argument passed to this thread
  int *myid = (int *)vargp;

  // Let us create a static variable to observe its changes
  static int s = 0;

  // Change static and global variables
  ++s; ++g;

  // Print the argument, static and global variables
  printf("Thread ID: %d, Static: %d, Global: %d\n", *myid, ++s, ++g);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid;

    // Let us create three threads
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun, (void *)&i);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I was just playing with aforementioned example in multithreading in C, and I got the same thread id for 2 threads and it shouldn't be because `myid` is a local pointer and should print different with each one.

I got the output as following:

```
Thread ID: 3, Static: 2, Global: 2
Thread ID: 3, Static: 4, Global: 4
Thread ID: 3, Static: 6, Global: 6
```

Can someone please explain me in brief?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass the *very same pointer* to all three threads. All threads will dereference the same pointer, getting the same value.

*And* because you call [`pthread_exit`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html), the data the pointer is pointing to will not be alive anymore. And that means the dereference will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

*Furthermore* since you access and modify shared data without synchronization you have data-races leading yet again to *undefined behavior*.

The first two problems can be easily solved by passing the *value* of `i` instead of a pointer to it. This is one of the very few cases where most people think it's okay to pretend that an integer is a pointer. You have to do some casting to make it work though:

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThreadFun, (void *) (intptr_t) i);
```

Then you have to do the opposite casting when getting the value:

```
int myid = (int) (intptr_t) vargp;
```

Comment: @P.P. I don't know if the lifetime of `i` in the `main` function have ended or not. Because `pthread_exit` doesn't return, does it mean that the lifetime of all variables in `main` will have the same lifetime as the process? Or does `pthread_exit` end the life-time of all variables in the current thread?

Comment: "does it mean that the lifetime of all variables in main will have the same lifetime as the process?" - no, their lifetime is over after `pthread_exit` call. The lifetime of `i` ends when the main thread exits i.e., when `pthread_exit` is called (or when the process exits). As soon as the `pthread_exit` call is made, it should be considered that all its resources are no longer accessible by other threads.

Comment: @ Some programmer dude, according to your answer,if the myid pointer keeps value 3 then ,it can't be  shifted to 1 or 2,means                                          
 Thread ID: 2, Static: 4, Global: 4
Thread ID: 3, Static: 6, Global: 6
Thread ID: 1, Static: 2, Global: 2
This is never possible.

Comment: @Shivanshu there's not much difference between `s` and `g` in your program. Both are "global" (their lifetime is valid until process exit) and their accesses cause *data race*.  `myid` has the same problem (but it's not "global" - its lifetime is restricted to the main thread) but it also has another problem.

Comment: where are you pointing by "also has another problem".Can you please elaborate @P.P.

Comment: @Shivanshu As noted, `myid` is pointing to `i` in `main` and when you call `pthread_exit`, the lifetime of `i` ends. So you can't continue to dereference `myid` (because what it's point to is no longer there).

Comment: Thread ID: 2, Static: 4, Global: 4
Thread ID: 1, Static: 2, Global: 2
Thread ID: 3, Static: 6, Global: 6
I am also getting the above result ,so according to your answer,once the thread id sets to 2 ,it can't go below 2 ,because the pointer is same for all threads,but i am getting the above answer.

Comment: @Shivanshu You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which makes you program unreliable and just simply wrong. There's no point in arguing about behavior if it's undefined (since it could be *anything*, including calling on [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)).

Answer (score 1):

> I got the same thread id for 2 threads and it shouldn't be because myid is a local pointer and should print different with each one.

`myid` is a local pointer, but it's actually pointing at an address from another thread. `myid` in all 3 threads you created pointed to the same address of `i` in main. So when you dereference `myid`, all threads read from the *same* location.

There are few issues.

1. Since `main` calls, `pthread_exit`, once the main thread exits and you can no longer access `i` from other threads. This is [undefined behaviour.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
2. All the threads actually read `i` (through `myid`). This is a [*data race*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/820-0619/geojs/index.html) - more than one thread accessing `i` without any
   synchronisation.

Note that *scope* of an object doesn't determine the *lifetime* of an object. They are related but not the same.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. corrects the problems found in the OPs posted code
4. checks for (most) error conditions
5. uses a proper signature for the `main()` function

And now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 3

// Let us create a global variable to change it in threads
int g = 0;

pthread_mutex_t myMutex;


// The function to be executed by all threads
void *myThreadFun( void *vargp )
{
    // Store the value argument passed to this thread
    int myid = (int) (intptr_t) vargp;

    // Let us create a static variable to observe its changes
    static int s = 0;

    pthread_mutex_lock( &myMutex );

    // Change static and global variables
    ++s; 
    ++g;

    // Print the argument, static and global variables
    printf("Thread ID: %d, Static: %d, Global: %d\n", myid, s, g);

    pthread_mutex_unlock( &myMutex );

    pthread_exit( NULL );
}


int main( void )
{
    pthread_t tid[ NUM_THREADS ] = {0};

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&myMutex, NULL) != 0)
    {
        perror( "pthread_mutex_init failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, init successful

    // Let us create three threads
    for ( int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        if(pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, myThreadFun, (void *) (intptr_t) i) != 0 )
        {
            perror( "pthread_create failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    //  collect the threads
    for( int i=0; i< NUM_THREADS; i++ )
    {
        if( pthread_join( tid[i], NULL ) != 0 )
        {
            perror( "pthread_join failed" );
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy( &myMutex );
    return 0;
}
```

A typical run of the program results in the following output:

```
Thread ID: 0, Static: 1, Global: 1
Thread ID: 2, Static: 2, Global: 2
Thread ID: 1, Static: 3, Global: 3
```

Note: the field claiming to be the thread ID is only the order that the threads were created, not the actual thread id.